# How do I introduce a side effect on the first subscription creation and last subscription disposal?

Tags: c#, .net, observable, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I have a class that has to perform setup/teardown to be able to produce events that get wrapped as observables. For brevity, I used Observable.Interval to produce an observable stream in the code below. What changes do I need in this code to get Start and Stop to be called twice? Effectively Start would need to be called each time the refcount increments to 1, and Stop called each time refcount decrements to 0.

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var provider = new SomeProvider();
        var s1       = provider.Subscribe(on1);
        var s2       = provider.Subscribe(on2);

        await Task.Delay(5000);

        s1.Dispose();
        s2.Dispose();

        var s3 = provider.Subscribe(on1);
        var s4 = provider.Subscribe(on2);

        await Task.Delay(5000);

        s3.Dispose();
        s4.Dispose();
    }

    private static void on1(long obj) => Console.WriteLine("on1");
    private static void on2(long obj) => Console.WriteLine("on2");

    public class SomeProvider : IObservable<long>
    {
        //Example observable stream
        readonly IObservable<long> timer = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Do(Start).Publish().RefCount();

        public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<long> observer)
        {
            var subscription = timer.Subscribe(observer);

            return new CompositeDisposable(subscription, Disposable.Create(() => { Stop(); }));
        }

        private static void Start(long obj) => Console.WriteLine("STARTED");
        private void Stop() => Console.WriteLine("STOPPED");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the previous answers, I created this extension method:

```
public static IObservable<T> OnSubscriptionDo<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Action subscribeAction, Action unsubscribeAction = null) =>
    (null == unsubscribeAction) ?
        source.CombineLatest(Observable.Return(Unit.Default).Finally(subscribeAction), (evt, _) => evt).Publish().RefCount() :
        source.CombineLatest(Observable.Return(Unit.Default).Finally(subscribeAction), (evt, _) => evt).Finally(unsubscribeAction).Publish().RefCount();
```

The "Do" is to provide some indication that this method introduces side effects. The observable stream is then defined like so:

```
readonly IObservable<long> timer = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).OnSubscriptionDo(Start, Stop);
```

Answer (score 1):

Any time you do `source.Publish().RefCount()`, the `Subscribe` method of source will be called when the reference count goes to 1 and the subscription will be disposed when the ref count goes to 0.  You can use this fact to implement the behavior you want.  Something like this should work (untested code below):

```
IObservable<T> MonitorSubscription<T>(IObservable<T> source, Action onSubscribe, Action onDispose)
{
    //TODO: argument error checking/handling
    return Observable.Create<T>(obs =>
        {
            onSubscribe();
            var subscription = source.Subscribe(obs);
            return Disposable.Create(() =>
                                     {
                                         subscription.Dispose();
                                         onDispose();
                                     });
        });
}
```

You would call this function where you had the Do with your Start and Stop functions.

`readonly IObservable<long> timer = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).MonitorSubscription(Start, Stop).Publish().RefCount();`

Now you will call Start when the ref count of timer goes to 1 and Stop when ref count goes to 0.

Comment: I kept playing around with this after I posted. This seems to work. Thougts?     readonly IObservable<long> timer = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).CombineLatest(Observable.Return(Unit.Default).Finally(Start), (evt, _) => evt).Finally(Stop).Publish().RefCount();

Comment: That looks like it should work.  It feels a bit "trickier" than my solution, but since you are likely to wrap either version in a function, the calling code won't notice the difference.  Note that if you want to put the Publish/RefCount into my version of the function, it would need to go outside the Create, not in the middle of source.Subscribe

Comment: I'd wrap the `.Publish().RefCount()` inside the `MonitorSubscription<T>` method. It seems like it is part of it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Empty`, `Finally` and `Concat` operators like this:

```
readonly IObservable<long> timer = Observable
    .Empty<long>()
    .Finally(() => Console.WriteLine($"Started"))
    .Concat(Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
    .Finally(() => Console.WriteLine($"Stopped"))
    .Publish()
    .RefCount();
```

The `"Started"` will be printed upon the first subscription, and the `"Stopped"` will be printed upon the last unsubscription.

Or you could use the extension method `OnSubscription` below. It should be slightly more efficient because it avoids the chaining.

```
/// <summary>Invokes a specific action before every subscription.</summary>
public static IObservable<T> OnSubscription<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Action action)
    => Observable.Create<T>(o => { action(); return source.Subscribe(o); });
```

Usage example:

```
readonly IObservable<long> timer = Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .OnSubscription(() => Console.WriteLine($"Started"))
    .Finally(() => Console.WriteLine($"Stopped"))
    .Publish()
    .RefCount();
```